# How to group on an aggregated data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

so I've to gather the data from the table such that

1.Group each order by shipment type.

2.Filter orders for which sum of sales at shipping group level is less than $35 however overall sales is greater than $35.

For eg: If an order has two shipping groups: S2H and SDD.
Then:

S2H = $20

SDD = $25

Order total = $45

In the above example the individual shipment total is less than $35, however order total is greater than $35.

I've tried till here and would like to know how can I move forward from here to get the desirable date:

```
SELECT                          
(CASE WHEN Sales > 35 AND Digital = 0 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                   
      ELSE NULL END) AS Above_SDD_Order,                                    
(CASE WHEN Sales <= 35 AND  Digital = 0 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                 
      ELSE NULL END) AS Below_SDD_Order,                                    
(CASE WHEN Sales > 35 AND Digital = 1 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 1 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                   
      ELSE NULL END) AS Above_SDD_S2H_Digital_Order,                                    
(CASE WHEN Sales <= 35 AND Digital = 1 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 1 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                  
      ELSE NULL END) AS Below_SDD_S2H_Digital_Order,                                    
(CASE WHEN Sales > 35 AND Digital = 0 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 1 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                   
      ELSE NULL END) AS Above_S2H_SDD_Order,                                    
(CASE WHEN Sales <= 35 AND Digital = 0 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 1 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                  
      ELSE NULL END) AS Below_SDD_S2H_Order,                                    
(CASE WHEN Sales > 35 AND Digital = 0 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 1 THEN order_no                                   
      ELSE NULL END) AS Above_Preorder_SDD_Order,                                   
(CASE WHEN Sales <= 35 AND Digital = 0 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 1 THEN order_no                                  
      ELSE NULL END) AS Below_Preorder_SDD_Order,                                   
(CASE WHEN Sales <= 35 AND Digital = 1 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                  
      ELSE NULL END) AS Below_Digital_SDD_Order,                                    
(CASE WHEN Sales > 35 AND Digital = 1 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 0 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                   
      ELSE NULL END )AS Above_Digital_SDD_Order,                                    
(CASE WHEN Sales <= 35 AND Digital = 0 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 1 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                  
      ELSE NULL END) AS Below_BOPS_SDD_Order,                                   
(CASE WHEN Sales > 35 AND Digital = 0 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 1 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                   
      ELSE NULL END) AS Above_BOPS_SDD_Order,                                   
(CASE WHEN Sales <= 35 AND Digital = 1 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 1 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no                                  
      ELSE NULL END )AS Below_Digital_BOPS_SDD_Order,                                   
(CASE WHEN Sales > 35 AND Digital = 1 AND SDD = 1 AND BOPS = 1 AND S2H = 0 AND PREORDER = 0 THEN order_no ELSE NULL END )AS Above_Digital_BOPS_SDD_Order                                    
FROM                                    
(SELECT order_no,                                   
MAX(CASE WHEN (Shipping_Group = 'DIGITAL_GIFT_CARD' OR Shipping_Group = 'DIGITAL' OR Shipping_Group = 'GAME_INFORMER_DIGITAL' OR Shipping_Group = 'LOYALTY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Digital,                                    
MAX(CASE WHEN Shipping_Group = 'GAME_INFORMER_PHYSICAL' OR Shipping_Group = 'PHYSICAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S2H,                                   
MAX(CASE WHEN Shipping_Group = 'PHYSICAL_PREORDER' OR Shipping_Group = 'DIGITAL_PREORDER' OR Shipping_Group = 'PICKUP_PREORDER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Preorder,                                        
MAX(CASE WHEN Shipping_Group = 'PICKUP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS BOPS,                                    
MAX(CASE WHEN Shipping_Group = 'SDD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SDD,                                 
SUM(pl_net_price) as Sales                                  
From                                    
(SELECT order_no, Shipping_Group,pl_net_price                                   
FROM                                    
eim-prod.EDW_VIEWS.ORDER_SUBMIT_PRODUCT_LINEITEM 
)                                   
group by 1)
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14;
```

You can also tell me if my approach is wrong and how I should take it further as I am a newbie with SQL. Thanks

Comment: Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use!

Comment: `having max(pl_net_price)  <35 and SUM(pl_net_price) >35`

Comment: @Serg Yeah, thanks mate. That's what I was looking for.